# Showing added mime types in REST media response

Tags: media, rest-api

I added extra mime types to the allowed list using

```
function enable_mime_types( $mimes ) {
    $mimes['svg']  = 'image/svg+xml';
    $mimes['yaml'] = 'application/x-yaml';
    return $mimes;
}

add_action( 'upload_mimes', 'enable_mime_types' );
```

And I can upload `yaml`files and `svg` files just fine in the admin. But when I look at the

`https://my-page.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/`

I can't see the `yaml` file anywhere, even though it's in the media library. The `svg` is visible along other images (`png` and `jpg`).

Comment: this sounds more like a bug report that should be reported on trac than an actual question

Comment: I thought that is some hidden intended way that REST needs to work XD I'll scour through the trac :+1:

Comment: hmm maybe, but it sounds more of a bug, worth opening one in any case as it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: If the yaml file is uploaded then can you please check the https://my-page.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/<attachment-id> maybe it'll show some information.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm getting 'rest_forbidden' when I try to access it by ID. And it must be something plugin wise blocking it, since on the clean install when I try it it shows the yaml file...

Comment: Ok, this is odd, I deactivated all plugins and switched to twentyseventeen but I still can't see the uploaded yaml file :S